# How to call shutdown hook from storm topology main class?

Tags: java, apache-storm, shutdown-hook

i have a storm topology class which starts a kafka spout and bolts. This class is main class. I am trying to clean exit storm topology, so i have created a shutdown hook in side that topology main method.

```
//Shutdown hook
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
        public void run() {
             System.out.println("Inside shutdown hook.");
             Utils.sleep(1000000);
             cluster.killTopology("netra-fault-management");
             cluster.shutdown();
             logger.info("Shutting down Topology.");
        }
    });
```

Here is my shutdown hook which is in main method of tolpology class. I run it from command prompt and when i do ctrl+c it is expected to run this shutdown hook but it just closes and no hook code is called . Do any buddy have idea about that how to run it on ctrl+c (SIGINT).

Answer (score 1):

With `Runtime#addShutdownHook`, it is possible.
The problem should be caused by `Utils.sleep(1000000);`. You should not "sleep" the shutdown thread as The Java Virtual Machine(and other applications) doesn't allow it. A shutdown hook is designed to be called when the application is about to be closed, to save important stuffs or unload resources, etc. The Java Virtual Machine will terminate after few seconds, even the thread isn't executed completely.

> In rare circumstances the virtual machine may abort, that is, stop running without shutting down cleanly. This occurs when the virtual machine is terminated externally, for example with the SIGKILL signal on Unix or the TerminateProcess call on Microsoft Windows. The virtual machine may also abort if a native method goes awry by, for example, corrupting internal data structures or attempting to access nonexistent memory. If the virtual machine aborts then no guarantee can be made about whether or not any shutdown hooks will be run.

From JavaDoc for Runtime class. Sometimes the shutdown hook will not be called. Good luck!

Comment: Hi jeremy thanks for answering but its not working. I have commented all code and just put one sysout and a log message but still got no success in calling shutdown hook ...

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 0):

See Nathan Marz commenting on a similar question years ago, I presume the behaviour has not changed:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/storm-user/A4-uFS6px2Y

Storm shuts down worker processes with SIGKILL, the JVM will not execute the shutdown hook under those circumstances (like it would for SIGINT).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood from [this](https://github.com/apache/storm/pull/143) and [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/STORM-183), they've implemented a change allowing the **shutdown hook** to fire, but the hooks code is **limited to one second**, so OK for some scenarios. Hovewer, I didn't check personally as it's not enough for my case which is buffer upload. But there is alternative [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32117845/how-to-call-a-particular-method-before-killing-a-storm-topology) for me that I'm going to implement.